# Converting a VARCHAR to NUMERIC - No Previous Post Answer Works For Me

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, numeric, varchar

I've read many responses to this same question, but none of the answers are working for my latest attempt at `CAST`ing a `VARCHAR` to `NUMERIC`:

```
Cast(Cast(a.VARCHARFIELD as NUMERIC(20,0))as INT)
```

The error I get is:

> The conversion of the varchar value '97264634555                        ' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded.

Unfortunately, the `a.VARCHARFIELD` contains accounts like `12345678999` but it also contains text or `VARCHAR` values like:

```
BALL                           
TWIN                          
12345678999                       
12345679000
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: You need to tell it not to pull ones that contain anything except numbers, for a start (wrap that part in a case statement).  Then your conversion should work.

Comment: `int` is generally too small for your values.

Comment: What is wrong with just `Cast(a.VARCHARFIELD as NUMERIC(20,0))`? The number you cast is apparantly too big for an `INT`. Perhaps you could use a `BIGINT` (at least that exists on SQL Server)

Comment: Using MS SQL, and I've tried case statements but my case statements did not work.  Also, I may need to do this CAST when I join a table that contains this field to another, so my CAST would need to work on the join as well.

Comment: Tried Cast(a.VARCHARFIELD as NUMERIC(20,0)) and the error message is 'Error converting data type VARCHAR to NUMERIC'

Comment: @GordonLinoff 's answer should fix that error.

Comment: TT - tried simply changing INT to BIGINT and I get the same error message as the one I just noted 'Error converting...'

Comment: Bob, how would I incorporate Gordon's answer?

Comment: Replace the whole thing, your `Cast(Cast( ... as INT)` with his answer except for the select: `(case when ... end)`

Comment: Gordon's answer below works - Thanks for the schooling Gordon and the rest of you.  In the case where I have to use the 'converted' field in a join it's table to another table, how would I do that? More specifically, I'm going to need to join the table this field is in to another table where the related field is numeric.

Comment: Give it a name: `(case when ... end) as ConvertedField`, then you can just refer to it as `ConvertedField`.

Comment: Gordon, Bob and company - thanks again!  Hadn't used a case statement in a join before but Gordon's solution also worked to properly join the tables using the 'converted' value.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to determine whether your value is a number.  There is no ANSI standard method, but an approximation is to just see if it starts with a number.

Second, `int` is too small, so I would recommend a decimal format.

So something like this would work on the data you provided:

```
select (case when VARCHARFIELD between '0' and '99999999999999'
             then cast(VARCHARFIELD as decimal(20, 0))
        end)
```

The validation of `number` can be done much better in any particular database; the form given is sufficient for the data provided in the question.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, a more accurate method would be:

```
select (case when VARCHARFIELD NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
             then cast(VARCHARFIELD as decimal(20, 0))
        end)
```

Comment: After this answer was posted, the OP mentioned that the RDBMS is MS SQL.  `ISNUMERIC` is the MS specific number validation.  Using that would be `... CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(VARCHARFIELD) = 1 THEN ...`

Comment: @EvilBob22. `isnumeric` returns 1 when there **at least one** numeric type that can be converted to. Not necessarily the conversion you want to make. `ISNUMERIC('$1')` returns `1`. `CAST('$1' AS NUMERIC(20, 0))` yields `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`  In other words, `isnumeric` is mostly useless.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance That is surprising, and I have used `ISNUMERIC()` before.  I assume SQL sees `$1` as type  `MONEY`, thus numeric, but you would think a conversion to `NUMERIC` wouldn't be an issue. (Maybe SQL assumes there *has* to be an allowed fractional value in the converted field.)

Comment: @EvilBob22, Yes `'$1'` can be cast to money. (True of other currency symbols) But currency symbols are invalid for other number types. However that was just an example `'1e99'` is numeric because it can convert to float and real but will overflow all the other numeric types. `'1.1'` passes `isnumeric` and can be cast to all types except the `*int` types. In special cases when you know that the errors in data will not be able to give false positives, `isnumeric` will work ok, but as a general to to protect against outside systems sending bad data, not so much.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Makes sense, and I do remember at least one case where we had to drop decimal values going to INT.  It is too bad we couldn't use a structure like regex's "1 or more of the previous character type" for it (`'[0-9]+'`), but it looks like Gordon's solution is the most elegant even in MS SQL.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this will work, because (for example) `'1a'` is `BETWEEN '0' AND '99999999999999'`, but fails when casting as `DECIMAL`.

Comment: The correct validation for integers in SQL Server is `col not like '%[^0-9]%'`.